# Как ограничить параллелизм в тестах junit 5

Tags: java, многопоточность, junit

Краткое описание - тесты junit 5 работают на встроенной многопоточке. В каждом создаются свои юзеры(экземляры определенного класса, являющегося ядром структуры) и над ним проводится тестирование. Пришла задача ограничить пул юзеров в 20 штук. Т.е. теперь все тесты будут "цеплять" юзеров из пула и работать с ними. Дело в том, что тестов много больше чем юзеров, да и бывает что в тесте используется 2 юзера. В общем подскажите библиотеку, которая это разрулит, не хочется самому писать) Надо чтобы на юзера, подхваченного тестом, накладывался лок до завершения теста и если свободных юзеров нет в наличии, чтобы тест ждал свободного юзера.

Comment: почитайте про ExecutorServise. ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(20)

Comment: юнит тесты должны быть изолированны друг от друга => в каждом юнит тесте должны быть свои 20 юзеров

Comment: @AzizUmarov это первое о чем  я подумал. Я к тому что может есть какие-нибудь обертки?

Comment: "встроенная многопоточка" это имеется ввиду используете опцию `junit.jupiter.execution.parallel.enabled`? И не совсем понятно, нужно ограничить количество потоков или количество максимально используемых пользователей?

Comment: @RomanKonoval именно эта опция, все верно. Количество потоков ограничивается средствами junit, нужно не ограничит количество максимально используемых пользователей, а переиспользовать свободных пользователей, а если свободных нет, то ждать пока они появятся

Comment: Я тут вижу противоречие в требованиях :) Если мы не ограничиваем количество пользователей, то как может случится, что нет свободных? Либо ограничиваем и ждем, либо не ограничиваем и тогда не ждем. Про повторное использование понятно.

Comment: @RomanKonoval все верно, не нужно ограничивать число максимально используемых юзеров, потому что их уже 20. Априори ясно что больше их не станет)

Answer (score 1):

Сначала задаем конфигурацию для junit5:

```
junit.jupiter.execution.parallel.enabled = true
junit.jupiter.execution.parallel.mode.default = concurrent
junit.jupiter.execution.parallel.config.strategy = fixed
junit.jupiter.execution.parallel.config.fixed.parallelism = 20
```

Это даст гарантию, что больше 20 потоков junit не запустит.

Далее нужно реализовать глобальный пул пользователей. Каждый тест перед запуском создает нужных ему пользователей с помощью пула. После окончания - тест возвращает пользователей в пул.

И самому реализовать несложно, а можно воспользоваться [готовым](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-pool/apidocs/org/apache/commons/pool2/impl/GenericObjectPool.html) из [apache commons-poool](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-pool/).

Если у важ уже есть список объектов, то вам нужно реализовать метод  `makeObject` из `PooledObjectFactory`, который будет возвращать готовые объекты один раз. Я не даю готовую реализацию и не тестровал это код, это скорее демонстрация, которая показывает, как эти приблизительно выглядит. Что-то типа :

```
class PrecreatedPooledObjectFactory extends BasePooledObjectFactory<User>{
  List<User> users;
  PrecreatedPoolObjectFactory(List<User> users) {
    this.user = user;
  }
  public PooledObject<User> makeObject() {
    User user = users.remove(user.get(0);
    return new DefaultPooledObject<User>(user);
  }
}

GenericObjectPoolConfig<User> config = new GenericObjectPoolConfig<>();
config.setMaxTotal(20);
List<User> precreatedUsers = ...
GenericObjectPool<User> pool = new GenericObjectPool<>(
   new PrecreatedPooledObjectFactory(precreatedUsers),
   config
);
```

И далее используете:

```
@BeforeEach
void setUp() {
  user = pool.borrowObject();
}

@AfterEach
void tearDown() {
  pool.returnObject(user);
}
```

Когда в пуле заканчиваются объекты, тест будет ждать в `setUp` пока другой тест не вернет их в пул.

Comment: Суть такая, что в пуле уже лежат подготовленные заранее пользователи.

Comment: Не понимаю проблему. Нужно всего лишь чтоб пул их возвращал, я добавил приблизительную реализацию с использованием commons-pool.

Comment: Попробую. Спасибо

Comment: Вы предлагаете реализовать все методы PooledObject?

Comment: Нет, используйте готовую реализацию из библиотеки.

Comment: "return new PooledObject<User>(user);"
Разве здесь я не должен реализовать все методы интерфейса?

Comment: Там есть готовая реализация, я дополнил. В ответе лишь набросок кода. Если вы решите использовать библиотеку - нужно почитать документацию, чтоб разобрать как она работает. Она позволяет реализовать свой пул объектов, сравнительно просто.